# unable to put a series of columns in a linebox widget in urwid

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, console-application, urwid

I am reading a yml form file and getting its contents as columns in urwid.
I have to display these columns onto the console.
If I use a plain listbox and listwalker then I am able to get the columns displayed on the screen.
However I need to group some of the columns as a block and show it in a linebox widget.
How can I do so ?

Each of my column widget has two columns, the first one being text widget and second one being edit widget.
This is what I tried :

1. tried to created a pile of columns by appending to a pile named as blockPile (declared as blockPile = urwid.Pile([ ]) )  as in below :
   `blockPile.contents.append(columnEntry, options='pack')`

   but got this error

   `TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'`
2. then removed the options and used this :

   `blockPile.contents.append(columnEntry)`

   but got following error

   `urwid.container.PileError: added content invalid: <Columns selectable box/flow widget>`
3. Next I used listbox

   `blockContent = urwid.SimpleListWalker([])

     blockListbox =  urwid.ListBox(blockContent)`

   and used append to fit my columns inside listBox
   `blockContent.append(columnEntry)`

   Finally to put the listbox in a box adapter

   `box = urwid.BoxAdapter(blockContent, height = 20)`

   and then return it in a linebox
   `return urwid.LineBox(box, title='|** Block **|')`

   but now I get following error
   `AttributeError: 'SimpleListWalker' object has no attribute 'selectable'`

Everything works fine if I use only a listbox and a listwalker and don't fit the listbox inside anything else.
But I want the list box of columns to be put in a linebox. How can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've played with urwid, but I think in urwid, in order to get a set of elements behave like a listWalker, you have to set an selectable attribute.

In this old code: https://github.com/Nic0/tyrs/blob/master/src/tyrs/widget.py#L95
I had to set the attribute selectable to True in my object containing a bunch of stuff, which give a twitter's status.

```
def selectable (self):
    return True
```

Anyway, you might want to the code to give you an idea.
Hope it helps.